# Complex Dynamic Collection Of UILabels Two Columns and Multiple Rows iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I've been struggling thinking how to setup this kind of layout in my tableViewCell. See photo:

More info:

1. Data is dynamic. There might be other days and each days might consists of multiple set of time.
2. Auto-layout is needed of course for dynamic/responsive height of my cell.

What I already did:

1. I did try doing this using IB.
2. I also tried it programmatically.
3. Both in IB and programmatically, I used `UIStackView`. But kinda hard to set it up.
4. I'm thinking to set it up using `UIViews` as containers, just like `UIStackView` but less complex.

I'm setting this up row by row. First is to line up the time vertically, and then the view or stackview of that will be paired horizontally with the Day. After that, do the same with the other days.

[image]

For formality of the question, here is a part of my code in my cell for setting up this layout, I suggest not taking an effort to read it, I believe I know what I am doing, and I think I just need another approach from you guys.

```
var job: Job! {
    didSet {

        _ = self.subviews.map {
            if $0 is UIStackView {
                $0.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }

        GPLog(classSender: self, log: "Setting up stackview for JobShift")

        // Add the main vertical stackView

        let stackView_Vertical = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
        stackView_Vertical.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView_Vertical.alignment = .fill
        stackView_Vertical.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stackView_Vertical.axis = .vertical
        stackView_Vertical.spacing = 16.0
        self.addSubview(stackView_Vertical)

        // Add constraints

        stackView_Vertical.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 15.0).isActive = true
        stackView_Vertical.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -15.0).isActive = true
        stackView_Vertical.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 15.0).isActive = true
        stackView_Vertical.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -15.0).isActive = true

        if let dummyJson = self.readJson() {
            if let shiftsJsonArray = dummyJson.array {
                for shiftJson in shiftsJsonArray {

                    let newShift = DummyDataShift(json: shiftJson)

                    if let day = newShift.day,
                        let schedules = newShift.schedule {
                        let generatedStackView = self.generateDayScheduleStackView(day: day, schedules: schedules)
                        stackView_Vertical.addArrangedSubview(generatedStackView)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Functions

// Generate the full schedule stack view.
func generateDayScheduleStackView(day: String, schedules: [DummyDataSchedule]) -> UIStackView {

    // label day (e.g. MONDAY)
    let newLabel_Day = self.shiftLabel
    newLabel_Day.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    newLabel_Day.text = day
    newLabel_Day.backgroundColor = .red
    newLabel_Day.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0).isActive = true

    // Prepare the vertical schedule stackView
    let stackView_Schedule = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
    stackView_Schedule.alignment = .fill
    stackView_Schedule.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView_Schedule.axis = .vertical

    // Add the schedules to the stackView vertically
    for schedule in schedules {
        let newLabel_Time = self.shiftLabel
        newLabel_Time.text = "\(schedule.timeIn!) - \(schedule.timeOut!)"
        newLabel_Time.backgroundColor = self.getRandomColor()
        newLabel_Time.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        newLabel_Time.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0).isActive = true

        stackView_Schedule.addArrangedSubview(newLabel_Time)
    }

    // Prepare the horizontal dayScheduleStackView
    let stackView_DaySchedule = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
    stackView_DaySchedule.alignment = .fill
    stackView_DaySchedule.distribution = .fillProportionally
    stackView_DaySchedule.axis = .horizontal

    // Add arranged subViews
    stackView_DaySchedule.addArrangedSubview(newLabel_Day)
    stackView_DaySchedule.addArrangedSubview(stackView_DaySchedule)


    return stackView_DaySchedule
}
```

Problem is: Lots of warnings for broken constraints, I do know how to set up and fix constraints. But when I fix it, nothing is displaying. I feel like I'm wasting my time pushing and trying hard to continue this approach. So I thought that it would be me a lot if I ask for suggestions?

Comment: I don't think your approach is not reasonable. What is your problem here?

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. I've edited my question. Anyways, I'm thinking to have `tableView` have multiple `sections` instead of rows. Then for this specific row, I'll make a section and have each day as rows. This is the best way I've every think of lol. Does deleting this question affect my rep?

Comment: "But kinda hard to set it up" Really?

Comment: Thanks for the comment and answer, I actually have solved it by utilizing the sections of the tableView, but I'm still using stackViews :).

Comment: There's more than one way to do things! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is multiple ways of solving your problem. I will try to give you one approach to it.

1) Use a TableView, with each section cell containing the "day of the week" label plus a vertical StackView for the time labels (use equal spacing).

2) If you set your constraints properly, you can return UITableViewAutomaticDimension on sizeForRow: delegate.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt 
    indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Then, on the cellForRowAt method, you can append labels to your vertical stack view with the times. The height of each cell will be correct as it will come from the constraints.

Comment: Thanks for this, just like what I've said in the comment section of my question, I've thought about this and did this - which helped me solve the problem. Will think about which of the two answers should be the answer. Keep answering questions here on SO. TY

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think stack views a perfectly good way to go. They are about arranging things in rows and columns, which is precisely what you want to do. I had no difficulty arranging some labels in imitation of your specifications, using stack views alone, in Interface Builder:

[image]

The delightful thing about stack views is that once they are configured properly, they adapt as arranged subviews are added or removed. So they are dynamic in exactly the way you desire.

Comment: Okay, but *how*? I want to accomplish the same thing but "I had no difficulty" doesn't really help explain what you did.